# Ehternet LAN not working at full speed

Tags: ethernet, file-transfer, lan

I have a PC and a Laptop connected with a ethernet cable. Using **ethtool**, i found that my speed is **1000Mb/s** which is **125MB/s**. But, when i am transferring 6GB file i get **~30MB/sec** speed.

How do i resolve this and get max speed?

Comment: What protocol? What kind of mass storage? Maybe you reached your hard drive limit...

Comment: I am using samba, and HDD.

Comment: Please, describe your network setup. I presume you have two machines connected each other with a switch in the middle. How fast can you go over the loopback (127.0.0.1)? Can you skip the switch and use a straight cable (possibly a cross ethernet cable) and try again? And, like @binarym, which protocol are you using? Could you try a plain ncat?

Comment: There is no switch, the wire is connected directly from PC to Laptop.

Comment: If both are Linux/Unix, please try with a cimple ncat setup. SMB is not among the most effective protocols. As the computing power of the two peers is involved, ncat should give you the bare minimum communication overhead. See this: https://nakkaya.com/2009/04/15/using-netcat-for-file-transfers/ Please post the ethtool output for both ends. The idea is that ncat will give you something very similar to the upper limit of the actuall speed you can achieve.
Please, use large files, not less than 50 to 100 MB. So you can involve also the I/O bottlenecks on either end.

Comment: @EnzoR I used necat, the download speed was roughly 58 MB/s. Also, the system became extremely slow.

Comment: 58MB/s is OK if any end is a 5400RPM hard disk. I got close to 100MB/s transferring files (1TB total) between two 7200RPM disks, using rsync over SSH.

Comment: @xenoid my source(pc) HDD is 7200RPM and dest(laptop) is 5400RPM

Comment: Write a big file  (several GB) to the 5400RPM disk using pv: `pv -raS -s 5G </dev/zero >./zeroes.dat`. That will tell you how fast your HDD can go on sustained writes.

Comment: The whole chaos is as week as it's weakest ring. Cpu, Ethernet and disk. To my personal rule of thumb 58 MB/s is about 580 Mb/s. And I agree with @Tayyab If the system becomes very slow, then there can also be a cpu-related bottleneck.